# Flot:how to align xaxis labels center over the tick line, and put labels in the plot area instead of outside space

Tags: alignment, axis, flot

I am wondering whether there's configuration to put axis ticks "center" over the tick line? and also put them in the plot area instead of outside space?

for the latter issue, i used "labelMargin:-30" in the grid options, while it made a difference than not setting this, however, no further difference if i set "labelMargin:-50" or using another bigger negative number. anybody knows how to deal with this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by putting the axis ticks "centered" over the tick line? I'm not sure what an axis tick is...

Answer (score 12):

I narrowed the bars on a histogram and centered the label under the bar, by formatting the bars as so:

```
series: {

      bars: {'show': 'true', 'align': "center", 'barWidth':0.7}

       }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same requirement and in the end I settled on styling the graph-specific `tickLabel` class

e.g.

```
#myGraph .tickLabel {
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

This worked for me because my x-axis has a fixed minimum and maximum - not ideal, but did the trick!

Comment: what if there are two axis. I am using the following but it is not working:
#myGraph .tickLabel .y2axis {
    margin-left: 2em;
}

#myGraph .tickLabel .yaxis {
    margin-left: 2em;
}

Comment: How can I add that code inside the `options` ? In the CSS it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Even I ahd something similar but for y axis and that too I was having two y axis so I performed the following and it worked:

```
 #graph_label .tickLabel {
           margin-left: 0em;
           margin-right:0em;
      }
```

***or***

```
#graph_label .yAxis .tickLabel {
           margin-left: 0em;
           margin-right:0em;
      } 

#graph_label .y2Axis .tickLabel {
           margin-left: 0em;
           margin-right:0em;
      }
```